# Conflicts between different JavaScripts and jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have integrated different JavaScripts on a site I'm making and now I'm experiencing conflicts between them. The site will sometimes never finish to load and an image slider will struggle to show its images.

Is there any good tools or ways to find these conflicts and fix them?

The page with the conflicts: http://cpanel12.proisp.no/~annaryuh/

Comment: The site looks good for me, I think, which browser are you using? I don't see any js errors in chrome

Comment: Sounds like you need [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: You're importing multiple versions of jQuery.  Don't do that.

Comment: @Pointy: Thank you! I've removed the oldest version.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: Thanks. I now use jQuery.noConflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can encapsulate your jQuery code in a new scope, so it won't conflict with the other libraries, something like this:

```
(function($){
     // your jQuery code here...
}(jQuery));
```

Also you can use jQuery's `noConflict` method to return the `$` symbol it's original value.

Answer (score 1):

Your site contains multiple versions of the same file to begin with. This will cause conflicts because multiple functions have the same names. (one example is [here](http://cpanel12.proisp.no/~annaryuh/wp-content/plugins/haiku-minimalist-audio-player/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js?ver=1.2) and [here](http://cpanel12.proisp.no/~annaryuh/wp-content/themes/annar2011/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js))

Comment: Ahh. Yeah. How did you know? Where you using a tool like Firebug?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It didn't solve the conflict with the image slider but probably some other future conflicts:)